# Add ContentEditorWebPart to the list of Safe Controls

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, safecontrols

I need to add the ContentEditorWebPart in the list of SafeControls because of [this](http://kiruthik.com/2010/10/05/YouDontHaveAddAndCustomizePagesPermissionsRequiredToPerformThisAction.aspx). Unless there's a better way...

The problem is, I don't want to add it manually, i want to do this automatically when I deplou my solution.

So I tried adding my safe control to the .spdata of the module requiring this, like this:

```
<SafeControls>
    <SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" TypeName="ContentEditorWebPart" Safe="True" />
</SafeControls>
```

but when I check my web.config, it changes the assembly to my projects assembly..

And if I add it to my package, i have to deploy the Sarepoint dll with it.

So What is the best way to add it to the SafeControls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I've decided to add a feature receiver which is gonna use `SPWebConfigModification` to add the safe control too the web.config

for details see [How to: Add and Remove Web.config Settings Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using of `SPWebConfigModification` in this case is redurantly.
This functionality can be archived by editing file `Package.Template.Xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Assemblies>
  <Assembly Location="Telerik.Web.UI.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
    <SafeControls>
      <SafeControl Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.2.912.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
    </SafeControls>
  </Assembly>
</Assemblies>
</Solution>
```

In this case I add assembly `Telerik.Web.UI.dll` in safe controls of web.config